# How can I automatically eject volumes I no longer use?

Tags: macos, automator, eject

I have a volume (saved as an encrypted sparsebundle) that I use from time to time.  For security reasons it should be ejected when not in use.  Of course I should do it myself, and usually I remember.  But not always.  Is there an automated way to do this as a back-up for fallible me?

Maybe a Folder Action attached to it that will eject it after a certain length of time (or even better, a certain length of time idle) or at a certain time of day?

Maybe a way to have it automatically ejected when the computer sleeps?  Currently, it is still there after computer sleep.  (I don't want to use logout because there are other processes I want to keep going.)

Comment: Do you have a file from within the volume open in an application while you "use" the volume? Maybe just a cronjob/LaunchAgent attempting to unmount the volume every 15' (and failing as long as a file is open) would work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to patrix, I now have it working.  I will post something here for others who want to do this in the future.

It seems that `cronjob` is no longer recommended, instead `launchd`.  This was the first time I wrote a launch agent, so there were many errors before I got it to work.  I could not decipher the error messages in the System log, but at least when they were there it told me it was not working.

I found a tutorial for a launch agent [on robots.thoughbot.com](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/example-writing-a-launch-agent-for-apples-launchd). Some of the ways he uses `launchctl` are marked "legacy" by Apple, but they still worked for me in Sierra.

Here is my launch agent plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.gae.umount1</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>diskutil</string>
        <string>unmount</string>
        <string>force</string>
        <string>/Volumes/3D</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It is supposed to execute the Unix command `diskutil unmount force /Volumes/3D` every 10800 seconds (= 3 hours).

Comment: Adding the LaunchAgent plist and the script it calls (if any) would be great, both for future visitors *and* as an opportunity to get more eyes to review your code (and give feedback if necessary).

Comment: Just a thought.....instead of forcing an unmount every three hours, you could run a script every 30 mins that checks if /var/sleepimage was modified and if it was, *then* unmount the volume.  This would mean that it just came out from sleep (which means no access) and you would be limited to a Window of only 30 mins.  Conversely, if you happen to be working for 3 hrs and 1 min, it won't eject the volume on you surreptitiously.

Comment: The hard counter is tricky anyway. If you start using the volume 5 minutes before the agent runs it will eject it even while you are still working with its content