# How to restart Mac Mail.app every night?

Tags: mail.app, cron, macos

I want to restart my Mac Mail.app software every night at 6am (or any time I choose).

What is the best way to do this?

I **DO NOT** want to reboot my whole Mac every night, only the Mail.app.

TIA.

**UPDATE 7th October 2021**

I have found a less complicated way than the suggestions below using the Automator app.

See: https://allthings.how/how-to-automatically-launch-and-close-an-app-on-mac-at-scheduled-times/

Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: It might be helpful to know _why_ you want to restart Mac Mail (in case this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I am using a mixture of exchange accounts and IMAP accounts and the mail app chokes at least once a day with the exchange accounts and resolves itself when I restart the mail app, so I just wanted the mail app to be restarted before I come into work so I am not sitting here thinking I am not getting email when in fact they are piling up without me knowing. I did not want to make a bg hoohaa about truble shooting that issue, just easier for me to automate the restart once a day or twice a day.

Comment: Back when I asked a question about getting my Mac to do something automatically, the advice I got said to use a launch agent, not cron.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310183/6824

Answer (score 2):

A cron job, something like

```
0 6 * * * killall Mail && open -a "Mail.app"
```

You can run as complicated a script as you want like the following

```
0 6 * * * sh path_to_the_script.sh
```

Add it to cron with `crontab  file_above.txt`

See `man crontab` for more info.

https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_*

Comment: Firstly, MacMail isn't the right name; and -- is it wise to killall Mail if it's already running?

Comment: @benwiggy did you see the Q edit history ? I don't verify whether  apps mentioned here exist or not. // sure one can find if the app is running, find the PID, send the right signal that they want etc etc. Treat this answer as a hint.